# C# WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler inside of foreach loop

Tags: c#

How do I cause the documentCompleted event to actually wait for completion inside a foreach loop.

The StaticStringclass.URLList is a list of websites, so just like www.google.com,www.aol.com.

Any advise is awesome.

StaticStringClass.holderList = new Queue();

```
        StaticStringClass.QueryHolder = new List<string>();
        StaticStringClass.CrawledBit = new List<string>();
        StaticStringClass.URLList = new List<string>();
        string startingHTML = "http://www.decodethis.com/Default.aspx?tabid=65&vin=";
        foreach (string listCar in StaticStringClass.CarIDs)
        {
            StaticStringClass.CarLister = listCar;
            string realModel = string.Empty;
            string realTrim = string.Empty;
            string htmlHold = string.Empty;
            string[] splitListCar = listCar.Split('|');
            string realvin = splitListCar[1];
            StaticStringClass.URLList.Add(startingHTML + realvin);
        }
        ProcessSites();
}
private Queue<string> downloadQueue = new Queue<string>();

    public void ProcessSites()
    {

        foreach (string siteList in StaticStringClass.URLList)
            downloadQueue.Enqueue(siteList);

        webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

        if (downloadQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            string nextSite = downloadQueue.Dequeue();
            webBrowser1.Navigate(nextSite);
        }





        //foreach (string siteList in StaticStringClass.URLList)
        //{

        //    webBrowser1.Navigate(siteList);
        //    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        //}


    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This approach will not work. `Navigate()` is an asynchronous operation - it will not have completed by the time you go to the next `siteList` in your `foreach` loop.

What is your use case here? If you are just trying to download these sites, use a `WebClient` instead or if you need to process the HTML use the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/):

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc =  web.Load("http://google.com");
var allDivs = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div");
```

Otherwise you could chain your site processing by using a download queue: In each completed event handler you do your regular processing then check if there are more sites to download, if so de-queue a site and call `Navigate()` again with the new site - rinse and repeat, i.e.:

```
private Queue<string> downloadQueue = new Queue<string>();

public void ProcessSites()
{
    foreach (string siteList in StaticStringClass.URLList)
        downloadQueue.Enqueue(siteList);

    webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

    if (downloadQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        string nextSite = downloadQueue.Dequeue();
        webBrowser1.Navigate(nextSite);
    }
}

void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //other processing here
    if(downloadQueue.Count > 0)
    {
        string nextSite = downloadQueue.Dequeue();
        webBrowser1.Navigate(nextSite);
    }
}
```

Comment: on how to chain these together.  I need the html from a script after the script is loaded or I would have just used a Webclient

Comment: @Mike: You'd rather use HtmlAgility pack for getting the html

Comment: I'm actually using HTMLAgilitypack later on in code, but i have to get the webpage completed first, also, where/what is downloadQueue?  I never get to webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted() because my loop never allows it to.

Comment: I'm sorry i just can't put together the example you have up top, not with the current code i'm using.  I can force the code to load google to call the documentCompleted but i'm really not sure what downloadQueue is or the .Dequeue is

Comment: Thanks for the sample, in the above sample when debugging it still never processes the .Navigate  is the webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
 in the right spot?

Comment: Could it be because the code that calls the first section above is stuck in a foreach loop?

Comment: Is `ProcessSites()` not even called? You should be able to debug and set a break point at the appropriate spots to find out what's going on.

Comment: Hey Broken, sorry for getting back to you, what happens is it looks through all of the que and then loads the last in que