# C# How to do WebBrowserDocumentComplete in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I thought this might be simple but i guess it's not, i have like 100 websites i need to load into a browser. I've loaded them into a List but my foreach happens before the website loads.  Does anybody have a way to make each of these load and actually process WebBrowserDocumentComplete before loading the next one? queue doesn't work.

```
foreach(string oneWebsite in ALLWebSites)
{
webBrowser1.Navigate(oneWebsite);
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new     WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}

 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
//do work
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample of what you have attempted ?

Comment: same as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678414/c-webbrowserdocumentcompletedeventhandler-inside-of-foreach-loop

Comment: -1 for being a blatant duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An AutoResetEvent should work

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waithandle.waitone(v=vs.71).aspx

```
static AutoResetEvent autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);


webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted); 
foreach(string oneWebsite in ALLWebSites) 
{ 
webBrowser1.Navigate(oneWebsite); 
autoEvent.WaitOne(new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), false))
}  

private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)     
{ 
//do work 
autoEvent.Set();
}
```

Comment: This may or may not work depending on what thread the DocumentCOmplete event it raised on.  I have a component that I tried using an autoresetevent for and its events are raised on the main UI thread.. so that doesnt work in that case.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the DocumentCOmplete handler have the browser navigate to the next site in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var websiteIndex = 0;
webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);

private void ProcessWebsite()
{
    if (websiteIndex < ALLWebSites.Count)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(ALLWebSites[websiteIndex]);
        websiteIndex++;
    }
}

 private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //do work

    // when work is done, process next one
    ProcessWebsite();
}
```